# What numbers is Brixton referring to?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, fast-and-furious-franchise, hobbs-and-shaw

In [*Fast & Furious Presents: Hobbs & Shaw*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hobbs_%26_Shaw), Shaw and Hobbs fight Brixton who is trying to upgrade the world
with a dangerous virus:

> BRIXTON: This doesn't end your way, boys.
>
> SHAW: Yeah, you keep telling yourself that.
>
> BRIXTON: **The numbers** don't add up for you.

What numbers is  Brixton referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an English term which means not making sense.

[writingexplained](https://writingexplained.org/idiom-dictionary/add-up) elaborated it more.